# Как открыть расположение файла ярлыка на удаленном компьютере bat файлом?

Tags: cmd, bat

Передо мной стоит задача написать bat файл, который бы переустанавливал windows desktop приложение. Для этого нужно написать bat файл выполняющий следующие шаги:

1. Войти в папку на удаленном компьютере в локальной сети по ip (10.0.0.100)
   Для того чтобы получить доступ необходимо указать имя пользователя и ввести сетевой пароль
2. В нужной папке лежат ярлыки инсталляторов. Нужно войти в расположение файла ярлыка и скачать .exe файл на компьютер в определенную папку. Читал что люди делают это с помощью robocopy

Я только начал работать с cmd, поэтому прошу помощи с решением

Comment: не могу сказать позволяет ли bat сценарий получить такую инфу.... js-сценарий - позволяет (рекомендую).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Справился с помощью wshshell:

```
net use X: \\10.0.0.100\Installations\_Last password /USER:login
@echo off
echo set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")>Tmp.vbs
echo set Lnk = WshShell.Createshortcut(WScript.Arguments(0))>>Tmp.vbs
echo WScript.Echo Lnk.TargetPath>>Tmp.vbs
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('cscript //nologo Tmp.vbs "X:\MPLCD_Beta.lnk"') do del Tmp.vbs & set installerPath=%%~d
xcopy %installerPath%
start Reinstall.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Обычно в таких случаях подключают сетевую шару как диск:

```
 net use X: \\10.0.214.190\share mysuperpassword /USER:Administrator
```

Копировать необязательно при помощи robocopy - можно и просто copy.

А вот залезть внутрь ярлыка - это не так просто. Может быть вам просто подойдёт размещать в шаре сами инсталляторы, а не ссылки на них?

Comment: К сожалению мне запрещено что-либо менять в работе удаленного компьютера. Ярлык, о котором идет речь указывает каждый раз на новый инсталлятор, а отслеживать путь до инсталлятора не представляется возможным